# Convert String to Date and fetch the difference

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi i have 2 dates in string format

base_date_string = 10-12-01 12:00:00
current_date_string = 10-12-23 10:18:00
both the above values are in string

i want to get the number of days elapsed between these 2 dates

I tried to convert them to NSDate using NSDateFormatters and then getting the difference.
I realised that string does not properly converts to NSDate

when i convert to nsdate i got
base_date:::2010-12-01 06:30:00 +0000
current_date::::2010-12-23 04:48:19 +0000 (the time portion is not perfect)

Formatter class that i used is:

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *base_date = [formatter1 dateFromString:@"10-12-01 12:00:00"];
    [formatter1 release];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter2 setDateFormat:@"yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *current_date = [formatter2 dateFromString:current_date_string];
    [formatter2 release];
```

//subrtrcation of basedate from current date to get elapsed number of days

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *diff = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit)                       
                         fromDate:base_date toDate:current_date options:0];
int date_value = [diff day];
```

Please any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

30 seconds in the `NSDate` documentation revealed:

[`-[NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-timeIntervalSinceDate_)

So using the dates in your question...

```
NSTimeInterval difference = [current_date timeIntervalSinceDate:base_date];
difference = fabs(difference);
NSLog(@"there are %f seconds between %@ and %@", difference, current_date, base_date);
```

**edit**

ok, so the problem is not date differencing.  You're observing that the string you're inputting is 5 and 1/2 hours ahead of the date you're getting back.

Well, let's look at this.  The date returned is in GMT time (as denoted by the `+0000`).  5 and 1/2 hours ahead of that is the timezone used in India.  So.  Are you in India?  If you are, then this is just a matter of needing to `-setTimezone:` on your `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: could u please tell me how should i use it

Comment: m a newbie so just where to use it

Comment: the date i get is not perfectly formatted so the days elapsed is not perfect,how to get the perfect date

Comment: m using this to get days elapsed::::::NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
 NSDateComponents *differenceComponents = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit) 
               fromDate:base_date
                 toDate:current_date
                options:0];

Comment: Dave the method i am using to get the days elapsed works fine but the problem is actually the conversion of string to perfect NSDates i hope coz they dont get properly converted

Comment: i found that if i change the base_date_string to 10-12-01 10:00:00 then days elapsed is 22 which is fine as per difference from current date.but still i feel is the conversion of string to date is proper?Will it work properly round the globe at any place?

Comment: Dave can u suggest me how to convert this time interval into number of days elapsed?I knw m asking basic questions but may be m not getting any perfect answer from my search

Comment: Yes m in India.
Is there any way to get time in UTC.As m not sure that app will be used by user in which time zone so how can i set that in advance

Comment: can i set the time zone like this: NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
 [formatter2 setDateFormat:@"yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; 
 [formatter2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
 NSDate *current_date = [[NSDate alloc]init]; 
 [formatter2 release];

Comment: but setting to local time zone still creates no effect.will this work round the globe?m not sure abt this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code of function to get the difference between 2 dates

```
-(int)howManyDaysHavePast:(NSDate*)lastDate :(NSDate*)today {
NSDate *startDate = lastDate;
NSDate *endDate = today;
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
unsigned int unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                            fromDate:startDate
                                              toDate:endDate options:0];
[gregorian release];
int days = [components day];
return days;
}
```

hAPPY iCODING...

Comment: Will gregorian calander give perfect values around the globe?Moreover if user is using any other calendar then in that case will this method work?

Comment: m already using current calander ::::NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; NSDateComponents *differenceComponents = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:base_date toDate:current_date options:0];

Comment: It will work as per the current time set in users iPhone. So doesnt matter where ever the user is... we r gonna get perfect result]

Comment: Whatever youu are using... the main thing that is function requires is the two dates for which its gonna find perfect days difference..

Comment: but Sir i feel the way m using to get the difference is similar to yours way but the string does not properly gets converted to NSDate.Will this method be perfect in this case also?

Comment: can u plz suggest me how to get perfect conversion of NSstring to NSDate.

Comment: the way you are doing is correct but make sure that the value in string matches exactly the formatter used to convert string to date..

Comment: This is what I have used in my code and its working perfectly                                                               
 NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *base_date = [formatter1 dateFromString:@"10-12-01 12:00:00"];
    [formatter1 release];
 
    NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter2 setDateFormat:@"yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *current_date = [[NSDate alloc]init];
    [formatter2 release];

 [self howManyDaysHavePast:base_date :current_date];

Comment: i am working as per your suggestions,i got the current_date = 2010-12-23 05:54:02 +0000 but actually it shows date in string as 2010-12-23 11:23:46 .Aren't the 2 are different.means conversion to dates is not proper?

Comment: can i set the time zone like this: NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
 [formatter2 setDateFormat:@"yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; 
 [formatter2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
 NSDate *current_date = [[NSDate alloc]init]; 
 [formatter2 release];

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *base_date = [formatter1 dateFromString:@"10-12-01 12:00:00"];

NSDate *current_date = [formatter2 dateFromString:current_date_string];
[formatter1 release];

NSTimeInterval difference = [current_date timeIntervalSinceDate:base_date];
```

Then you will get difference in number of seconds. Then you can get in number of days as following

```
float days = difference/86400;
```

The "days" consists the number of days that the current_date is differ from the base_date.